# Let's become queen and king together on prom night

Tags: word-choice, expressions, idioms, slogan

I am trying to make a sentence for a prom night party. It is kind of slogan.
Is the sentence below good? If not, could you give some alternative versions.

**Let's become queen and king together on prom night.**

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help], as our guidelines explicitly state that the site is not suitable for help with writing, and in any case our Q&A format is ill-suited to open-ended requests for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a party slogan, you are addressing all the invitees. While there is presumably only one king and queen of the prom, you could entice everyone by saying,

Become Royalty on Prom Night! or Be Royal! or some play on words similar to what sports teams named Kings/Royals etc do, like, Take the Crown, Wear the Crown, Party like Royalty, Party like Kings and Queens, etc. something along those lines.